# HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5, javascript

Использую плагин от blurjs.com, проблема в том, что все мои изображения хранятся на поддомене и из-за этого выкидывает ошибку доступа. Это можно обойти? Или вообще никак?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно включить [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) для нужных типов файлов на этом поддомене:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin   *
```

и грузить [изображения с cross](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image):

```
var img = new Image;
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.onload = function (){ /*...*/ };
img.src = "...";
```

Comment: За что отвечает crossOrigin?

Comment: Добавляю
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
В .htaccess и у меня вообще изображения перестают грузиться